# Angular Highchart multiple values in tooltip

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

Im working on a highchart. The array for series looks something like this:

```
graphData = [{name:"Thunder", data:[['11PM',3726],['5PM',2344]]},
             {name:"Hurricane", data:[['11PM',5736].['5PM',5244]]}]
```

For the tooltip, if I hover over lets say 11PM on either line, i want to show data from both Thunder and Hurricane. Right now, it only shows data from the corresponding graph line.

```
tootlip:{
pointFormat: "{point.series.name}: {point.y:0f}"
}
series: this.graphData
```

Suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable shared tooltip:

```
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hpkLgjbs/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.shared

Comment: That was it. Thank you

Comment: Quick ad-on question: How do I get the difference between the data (data1 - data2 for eg) and display in the shared tooltip?

Comment: Hi @user11968622, You can use `pointFormat` or `pointFormatter` function for an individual series. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u152ezas/

Comment: Thanks friend! Much appreciated